# user registration and login module for drupal 7.22

Tags: php, drupal

I am new to php.I want to create a user login ans registration page in drupal.anyone can help me to find this module. Please help me out

Answer (score 0):

By default drupal will have User Registration/Login System. What else are you looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Drupal comes with login and registration page!